# Will feature receiver get activate if user has no permissions to a site?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers, access-denied, feature-receiver

Here's what I need...User does not have access to a site (http://myserver/sites/MySite). When user tries to access they are redirected to ugly AccessDenied.aspx.

I was researching and found that using VS I can create a custom application page that user can be redirected to. I created the app page, a feature and added an event receiver to it. 
No matter what I do I can't get the code execute.

If user has no permissions to site does the feature ever get activated? If not, what other choices do I have to redirect to custom access denied page?

Thanks,
Ninel

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you will need Event Receiver for your purpose, please find this thread of stackexchange [SP 2010 Custom Access Denied Pages](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23753/sp-2010-custom-access-denied-pages-403-error)

For help with command you may find this [MSDN Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607768.aspx) helpful

For details steps please go through this [Customize the Access Denied Page](http://sharepointdiva.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/customize-the-access-denied-page/)

Comment: Is there any way to have different custom Access Denied pages for each site? The reason I ask is becuase I would like to display contact information on each of these custom pages and the contact info is different for each site.